# Can a view return multiple result sets?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I would like to have a view that I could run return multiple result sets. Is this possible?

If a view can not do this, then is there another object with High Visibility/Transparency within SQL Server that can achieve this? (I like using a view because I can easily see it and run it under the Views folder). A stored procedure is not really ideal because I have so many.

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to see?

Comment: Multiple result sets?  Could you provide an example of how you interpret this to work?

Comment: This just sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Why does it sound like a bad idea? Storing reusable queries has been around since access. In SSMS you can save queries as .SQL files, but they aren't transparent. I want something within the environment that is readily visible, and I can run like a View. It would be nice if their was a Queries folder. I need this because I need to see/analyze data from test accounts within the database. It would be much faster to right-click execute query rather than browse for file (which could be way deep in the file system) then run it. It works for Views which are like queries, so it will work for Queries

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No it can't and I think a stored procedure is your only option here.

Maybe you could put it in a particular schema or naming convention (e.g. prefix with `__` so it's sorted at the top) to make it more visible. In SSMS you can assign shortcut keys to run particular stored procedures - does that help?

Obviously if  the result sets happen to be `UNION` compatible you could combine them in A View but that still only returns a single result set.